# In Laravel 4 Using creating a many to many relationship between 2 databases

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, orm

Hello I have a single connection/database server that houses more databases from different departments.

I am trying to make a Laravel eloquent model relationship between the different databases and I just can't seem to find a way to do this using eloquent.

Right now we are using the DB query builder to make this relationships happen but we are tring to refactor using eloquent.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me solve this issue by telling me if this is possible or not.

For example we have the X database with x1 x10 tables and we need to have relationships for the Y databse having tables y1 to y20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use Eloquent or the query builder, this can be done and is pretty simple.

You have to set up multiple connections, one for each database, in the database config files. Say your connection names reflect the database names, x1,x2,x3 etc.

Then you have to set the connection in your Eloquent model.

In the Eloquent model, add the following:

```
protected $connection = "x1";
```

Where x1 is the connection name (not the database name).

Then just build your relationships, for example:

```
public function x2(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Y1');
}
```

Where Y1 is the Eloquent model class name.